# JS jQuery each loop filter append list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making an ajax call with grabs data which looks like this:

```
{
    "cars":[{
        "id":"654",
        "type": "ford",
        "active": "1"
    },{
        "id":"650",
        "type": "fiat",
        "active": "0"
    }]
}
```

I then use the data to populate a selectbox with this code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'myurlhere',
    method: 'GET',
    async: false,
    success: function(result) {

        $.each(result, function(result, value) {
            $('#myselect').append($('<option>').text(value.id).attr('value', value.id));
        });

    }
});
```

My problem is that I only want to populate the select with data which have **active = "1"** (for the data)

So I've done this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'myurlhere',
    method: 'GET',
    async: false,
    success: function(result) {

        if (value.active = 1) {
            $.each(result, function(result, value) {
                $('#myselect').append($('<option>').text(value.id).attr('value', value.id));
            });
        }

    }
});
```

but this is not filtering it and still returning all.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you need to remove `async: false` as it's very bad practice to use it.

Secondly, you can use `filter()` on the `result.cars` array to find only this where `active` is `'1'`:

```
var data = result.cars.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.active == '1';
})

$.each(data, function(result, value) {
    $('#myselect').append($('<option>', {
        text: value.id,
        value: value.id
    }));
});
```

Alternatively you could do it in the `$.each` loop itself, but note that you need to loop through `result.cars`, not `result`:

```
$.each(result.cars, function(i, value) {
    if (value.active == '1') {
        $('#myselect').append($('<option>', {
            text: value.id,
            value: value.id
        }));
    }
});
```

It would depend on how many active elements are in the array as to which of the above methods would be quicker, although there probably won't be much of a difference in real terms. Ideally you could amend the response to only return active objects, but I assume this is a third party API and therefore out of your control.

Answer (score 2):

Your if statement is doing an assignment, not checking equality, for starters.  Needs to be `value.active === "1"`  Also, you want the if statement inside the .each method, not outside.

Comment: You're absolutely right, thank you.  I edited the answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if it doesn't work.
Hope this helps.

```
.ajax({
    url: 'myurlhere',
    method: 'GET',
    async: false,
    success: function(result) {
        $.each(result.cars, function(key, value) {
            if(value.active == 1) {
                $('#myselect').append($('<option>').text(value.id).attr('value', value.id));
            }    
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Can someone  let me know where I went wrong? Why is it downvoted?

Comment: A little explanation of what you have done or what was wrong with OPs code is always helpfull. Code only answer are subject to getting deleted in the review queue

Comment: In terms of the code, you have unbalanced parentheses on the append so it just doesn't work. I generally try my answers first (jsfiddle for example) to make sure it works.

Comment: Corrected the mistake. Thanks.